# Fill in an array using loop with multiple variables (new to Python, old to C++ (back in the day))

Tags: python, arrays

Basically what I want to do is create something like this in python (this is basic idea and not actual code):

```
n = 3
i = n + 1
a = [1, 3, 3, 1]
b = [1, 2, 1]

while n > 1:
```

Check if n is even
- if n is even, then for all i in range(0,n), insert values into an array using the formula below
- b[n-i] = a[n-i-1] + a[n-i], this value will replace the previously given value of b[] above the code.
- Print out the array
- After each area is filled, n+=1, i=n+1 are applied, then the loop continues

Check if n is odd
- same process except formula is
- a[n-i] = b[n-i-1] + a[n-i], this value will replace the previously given value of a[] above the code.
- Print out the array
- After each area is filled, n+=1, i=n+1 are applied, then the loop continues

This process will loop and print each and continue on, the arrays will essentially look like this:
b = [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], a = [1 5, 10, 10, 5, 1], b = [1, 6, 15, 20, 20, 15, 6, 1], etc.

Here is the code that I currently have, however I'm getting an 'out of range' error.

---

```
n = 3
i = n + 1
b = [1, 2, 1]
a = [1, 3, 3, 1]

while n > 1:

if n%2==0:
    print("even")
    for i in range(0,n):
         b[n-i].append(a[n-i-1]+a[n-i])

else:
    print("odd")
    for i in range(0,n):
        print("yay")
        a[n-i].append(b[n-i-1]+b[n-i])

if n%2==0:
    print(b)
else:
    print(a)

n +=1
i = n + 1
print("loop")
```

---

The random prints throughout the code are to test and see if it is even making it into the process.  There were from a previous code and I just haven't removed them yet.

Hopefully you can help me, I can't find anything online about a loop that constantly increases the size of an array and fills it at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry struggling with the code that's in the sample. From your description I can see that you want to generate Pascal's triangle. Here's a short snippet that will do this.

```
a = [1, 1]
for _ in range(10):
    a = [1] + [x+y for (x,y) in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])] + [1]
    print a
```

`a[:-1]` refers to the whole array except the last element and `a[1:]` refers to whole array except first element. `zip` combines first elements from each array into a tuple and so on. All that remains is to add them and pad the row with ones one the outside. `_` is used to tell Python, I don't care about this variable - useful if you want to be explicit that you are not using the range value for anything except flow control.

Comment: thank you, I'll give it a shot and yes it was pascal's triangle. Good eye :P

Comment: It works great until it hits 35 and then it prints 2319959400L and continues to print L's after the numbers past that point. 

Ideas?  I only set the range to 100 and I would like it to work as long as possible. Obviously a different language would help as python is 32 bit and not 64; however, I'm not sure what language I should use if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Maria's answer is perfect, I think. If you want to start with your code, you can rewrite your code as below to get similar result. FYI.

```
n = 3
b = [1, 2, 1]

while 1 < n < 10:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print("even")
        b = [0] * (n + 1)
        for i in range(0, n + 1):
            if i == 0:
                b[i] = a[0]
            elif i == n:
                b[i] = a[i - 1]
            else:
                b[n - i] = a[i - 1] + a[i]
    else:
        print("odd")
        a = [0] * (n + 1)
        for i in range(0, n + 1):
            if i == 0:
                a[i] = b[0]
            elif i == n:
                a[i] = b[i - 1]
            else:
                a[i] = b[i - 1] + b[i]

    if n % 2 == 0:
        print(b)
    else:
        print(a)

    n += 1
    print("loop")
```